# Cant access servers on network, but I can access them from outside the network

Tags: windows, networking, ping, desktop

So this is a very strange problem that I have never encountered before. Let me start with a diagram of the network.

[image]

The problem is I have a few servers that are on my modem. Each server is assigned static ips. (1.1.1.34, 1.1.1.35)

These servers are configured properly as I am able to reach them from the outside world, and I can ping to and from. So i know that they have internet.

The issue becomes when I try to access them from my computer that is on the same modem. This computer is assigned dynamic IPs based on the modem itself (10.1.10.15). You know your typical local IP address.

When i run CMD i am able to ping those servers which I am assuming that is because we are all behind the same modem. But when I actually go to a web browser to access either the software platform that is on ip 1.1.1.34 or a website that is on server 1.1.1.35 I have no luck. I am not even able to ssh into the servers from this computer. But I can however ssh from another computer from the outside world.

Thanks for your help in advance.

*** UPDATE ***

As I am troubleshooting myself I will continue to keep updated on here.

I also now have ruled out a desktop computer issue. As I just connected my laptop via wifi and the same issue persists. I cannot view those websites.

I am going to look into the modem on the network.

Comment: Without knowing all the details, I would suggest checking your sub net configurations. Make sure that everything that you want to be able to "talk" is configured in such a way that they are on the same sub net or within the same sub net range. We had an issue here where people in the lab who were on x.x.x.40 couldnt talk to the servers on x.x.x.29 even though they were on the same network. If this is not the culprit try renewing your IP's and giving it another go. I had a case where I could access my remote servers but not my gateway server. I simply refreshed the IP and it worked.

Comment: Yea I have renewed my ips several times.

Comment: I would have thought about the subnet as well. Which makes a little sense because they are on different subnets. The servers are on 255.255.255.248 and the computer was assigned 255.255.255.0. But the only place that doesnt make sense is that the servers are web servers so it shouldnt matter what subnet a computer is on. They should have the ability to be able to be accessed from any computer around the world. Which they are except my desktop.

Comment: well externally they are probably communicating through some additional routing, however Internally your "routing" is your router/switch however you have that all set up. for example I am more than likely not on the same sub net as any of the websites I visit, however I can access them via some entity. But if I was trying to communicate with something internally and we were talking on different channels then there would be a gap if that makes sense. Not to mention why don't you try changing the sub net just to verify its not the issue? unless of course you are hosting or something.

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms Yes sin a sense that makes sense to me. So the problem that I am facing with that is. 1. this is the same configuration that I had at the other location. The only thing that i did was change the statics. 2. If that was the case. I cant even go into any computer and change the subnetmask, because i get an error that it doesnt belong with the gateway. Then I change the gateway and I get an error that it is not the correct gateway and I loose internet. By the way the gateway that is dhcp is typical local 10.1.10.1 where as the gateway i configure on servers are 1.1.1.38.

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms and also on the computer when I do a "what is my IP" it does show that my outward facing IP is 1.1.1.38

Comment: I'm pretty sure all setup's should be using the router as the default gateway. It sounds to me that you have deeper networking issues going on here. I would suggest looking into whats off with the new setup in comparsion to the old one if you still have the details. In my experience I always point my servers back to the desired gateway as the main access point so that everything can communicate properly. In my case it was my DHCP /PXE server I used as the default gateway but this was for an internal private network. try changing server gateways to the router gateway and see if you can "talk"

Comment: I guess wifi box running as a router.  Did you set any custom routes on wifi box? Does wifi using static IP on WAN side? Did you tried to restart wifi box?

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms "I'm pretty sure all setup's should be using the router as the default gateway" IMHO it is bad idea. Right now LAN isolated from internet and in case one of the server might be compromised it wouldn't be fun, besides  of increasing possibility to DDoS all servers in case one compromised. @OP Could you add result of `mtr` tracing from LAN to one of the server?

Comment: Well if its not a sub net issue the only other thing that It could be is incorrect setup or he needs to re-direct his traffic to the gateway in order for everything to be able to "talk". Otherwise what means of access does he have to be able to communicate between his servers? I get that he wants it to be isolated but he also wants it to be able to communicate internally. I don't think resetting the "Wifi box" is going to help because the boxes don't have a proper medium of access to communicate amongst each other. only other option is to point one server to the others gateway.

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms So that is the wierd thing. All servers are using the router as default gateway. I just logged in to the comcast router. The routers gateway is the 1.1.1.38. What i see is the local IP setup for setting up the DHCP. There the settings are the same as at the last location 10.1.10.1 as a gateway and 10.1.10.2-256 as the local ips to assign.

Comment: @Alex The wifi is setup on the comcast modem/router. Everything has been restarted multiple times.

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms So i did end up setting the static IP address to the desktop which allowed me access the sites properly. This tells me it is a potential subnet issue, as now the subnet is identical to the subnet of the servers. While this is a quick fix just for troubleshooting purposes, it doesnt solve the problem. Now i could go ahead and set a static ip for switch to  then propagate all the computers connected to it. But that doesnt do much for me on wifi devices such as printers. I will then no longer be able to pring.

Comment: So wifi box on your picture is comcast's box? I advise you then to get some firewall/router/wifi and assign on WAN side static IP that left and use you desktop PC behind this new router to avoid expose LAN directly to internet

Comment: Again this is the same setup at the other location. All the way down to the same desktop computer with the same local ip 10.1.10.15 and same gateway 10.1.10.1 while the servers were on the routers gateway. As far as I know about networking and Maybe I could be wrong. But even though my local ip through dhcp is 10.1.10.15 and GW of 10.1.10.1 it is just for routing purposes and routes that computer back to the modem which is actually using the gateway of 1.1.1.38...

Comment: Not to mention the other elephant that was already brought up. We are never on the same subnetmask of the sites we are trying to reach, therefore it shouldnt matter since the servers them selves have internet I should be able to access them like i can access any other website from the same computer

Comment: @Alex okay I have another wifi router lying around. Let me see if that fixes the issue

Comment: As we expected, sub net issue. if you manually set up the sub netting and DHCP then you could try adjusting the range of the sub net from the DHCP configuration. Depending on if it is a Linux box or windows the setup will vary in steps. This will make it so that in future when using DHCP there are no "roadblocks". Also i reference to Alex's point about security, another option would be to throw an additional router in front of the other server and have them communicate from router to router. However depending on network size and application I would find it rather unnecessary.

Comment: Comcast boxes are really weird thing(!!!) If you assigned to the server external static IP, it means comcast box is in bridge (or pseudo bridge) mode. If you using static IPs, DO NOT hook any sensible devices(as workstations) directly to comcast modem. The only devices that know how to protect themself and only as static IP. You would be still able to access comcast box via 10.x.x.x to manage its weird settings even if you would set exta firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we figure out that `WiFi` box on the picture is Comcast's gateway and you was able to set up issued to you by comcast static IP's, it is means that gateway working in bridge (or to be precise - pseudo bridge) mode.

I advise you then to get some firewall/router/wifi and assign on WAN side static IP that left (from issued to you 5 of them) then hook it to Camcast's box and use you desktop PC behind this new router to avoid exposure of workstations on the LAN side directly to internet.

You would be still able to access comcast box via 10.1.10.1 address to manage its weird settings even if you would set extra firewall behind comcast box as I suggested. (You can also access comcast box via gateway IP address, but only in case if you are on the same public subnet, from servers for example.)

Also change default `'highspeed'` password on comcast box, if one of your server might be compromised, attacker wouldn't be able to screwed up comcast box settings.

One more advise, - do not use WiFi feature on comcast box or use it only as a guest WiFi

Comment: Hey Man thanks for all of your help with this. Yes that seems to be the issue. As soon as I put a new router in and assigned it one of my statics and put my computers behind it everything worked perfectly. It is a very strange thing that comcast does. I even had a tech come out and asked him about and he had no clue and just said "Well, thats comcast for you." Lol Appreciate all of your help

Comment: @Bill I glad my answer helped you. I just want to point out, in case some1 else would  have the same problem that information above related only to "new" comcast's modems that has WiFi on board. Those who still use old business SMC modem works completely differently, there no such "pseudo bridge" features.